# OpenGL and Nvidia Problem with Manjaro after trying to configure settings

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, opengl, playonlinux

I didn't have any problem with my Graphics driver or OpenGL before, and I was able to play 3D games using POL. But when i was just looking around in my system I came up with `nvidia-settings` so when I started it up it gave me a message saying

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X
>   configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart
>   the X server.

So I searched the Wiki about this problem and then I found [this Wiki page](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Configure_NVIDIA_%28non-free%29_settings_and_load_them_on_Startup).

I went along with the tutorial, I noticed that I already had the correct driver installed. However, hoping to get Nvidia graphics to work on Xserver, I generated a Xorg configuration file at /etc/X11/mhwd.d/nvidia.conf

And then I ran `sudo mhwd-gpu --setgl nvidia --setxorg /etc/X11/mhwd.d/nvidia.conf` to select that configuration.

I noticed that I already had a .conf file named `intel.conf` there. However, The Xserver failed to restart when I pressed ctrl + alt + backspace.

I reset the Xorg using `sudo mhwd-gpu --setgl nvidia --setxorg /etc/X11/mhwd.d/intel.conf`

Which gave me my GUI back but now I can't run any game. Whn I am starting PlayOnLinux it says that

> PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL libraries.
>   You might encounter problem with your games

and

> PlayOnLinux is unable to find 64bits OpenGL libraries.
>   You might encounter problem with your games

I will upload any log files needed.
Thanks in advance,
Bhashithe

Comment: I made some progress, removed nvidia drivers, removed xorg and removed xorg.config i had, then i reinstalled xorg and reconfigured xorg and rebooted the laptop. Then I reinstalled the drivers at mhwd.

Still i am getting the error message when I `--setgl nvidia`, but I can play games without any problem now if i am at `--setgl mesa`

Comment: I followed this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/507468/playonlinux-missing-opengl-32-libraries?newreg=ee8eaf49bf6b491185d7dcbeae7432a4)